# Bootstrap card image doesn't take up available height when displayed as a row

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I added images to my Bootstrap 4.3 cards. These images have different dimensions. In some cases these images don't take up all the height that is available to them, as shown in the snippet display full screen.

I can circumvent this problem by adding the class `h-100` to the `img`. However on small screens, the image and card body stack up and the image takes a lot of precious screen space. Adding either of the classes `w-100` or `img-fluid` to the `img` in the cards also led to no avail.
Is there an obvious solution to this or should I create a new class for the img and use `object-fit: cover` to solve my problem?

Kind regards

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="card mb-3 w-75 mx-auto shadow">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <img src="https://www.win-nieuws.nl/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/JVOfreefeet-verkleind-848x478.png" class="img-fluid" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
        <p>Ut in voluptate sit, qui epuletur, in dolore, qui torqueatur. Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Torquatus, is qui consul cum Cn. Res enim fortasse verae, certe graves, non ita tractantur.
        </p>
        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="card mb-3 w-75 mx-auto shadow">
      <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <img src="https://www.e-architect.com/images/jpgs/holland/building_x_zwolle_b120511_2.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p>Ut in voluptate sit, qui epuletur, in dolore, qui torqueatur. Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Torquatus, is qui consul cum Cn. Res enim fortasse verae, certe graves, non ita tractantur.
            </p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <hr>

<div class="card mb-3 w-75 mx-auto shadow">
      <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <img src="https://www.weblogzwolle.nl/images/stories/mei.%202010%20B/gebouw_x_1.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p>Ut in voluptate sit, qui epuletur, in dolore, qui torqueatur. Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Torquatus, is qui consul cum Cn. Res enim fortasse verae, certe graves, non ita tractantur.
            </p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```